# EOFError when reading pickled data

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, pickle

I'm trying to unpickle chunks of a webpage stored in the Google App Engine memcache. First I get the chunks and store them as a dictionary with the key

```
def get_by_key_name(key_name):
    result = memcache.get_multi(['%s.%s' % (key_name, i) for i in xrange(32)])
    serialized = ''
    for k, v in sorted(result.items()):
        if v is not None:
            serialized = serialized.join(v)
        else:
            return None

    return pickle.loads(serialized) #Line that fails
```

For some reason it raises EOFError. The code that originally pickled the data is:

```
serialized = pickle.dumps(content, 2)
values = {}
for i in xrange(0, len(serialized), chunksize):
  values['%s.%s' % (key_name, i//CHUNKSIZE) ] = serialized[i:i+chunksize]
```

Anybody have any idea why? By the way, CHUNKSIZE is 950000 bytes. I tried to load reddit's front page onto the memcache, so I don't think it is exceeding this limit.

Comment: In your pickling code, where's guarantee that you'll end up with a `${key_name}.31`? Your loading code assumes that it must be there. If you're failing where you say you're failing, I'm thinking that there code you aren't showing us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to concatenate the string, not join.

```
serialized += v
```

Join will add a copy of the original string between each character of the new string

```
>>> 'hello'.join('there')
'thellohhelloehellorhelloe'
```

I'm kinda impressed you didn't run out of memory!

Comment: Still doesn't work. However you were right about join()

Comment: @twerk_it_606 - hmmm, more than 32 chunks? Some chunks expired? You could gather 33 chunks and if you actually get that last one, treat it as an overflow (or keep fetching). And assert if any intermediate items are None. Finally, you could encode a length and hash in the data for verification.

Comment: I already checked to see if any of the values were `None` using `if v is not None`. Also I don't think it is more than 32 chunks, as each chunk is 950,000 bytes, and I tried to load reddit.com onto memcache, which is much smaller.

Comment: Suppose chunks 3 and 7 were dropped, you wouldn't catch it. That's why it would be interesting to have more info. Like maybe a header `'%s.header' % key` that holds each chunk count and a hash.

Answer (score 1):

You are joining your string incorrectly:

```
serialized = ''
for k, v in sorted(result.items()):
    if v is not None:
        serialized = serialized.join(v)
```

This uses `selialized` as built so far as the joining string, with the new string treated as individual characters:

```
>>> serialized = ''
>>> for v in ('foo', 'bar', 'baz'):
...     serialized = serialized.join(v)
... 
>>> serialized
'bbfooafoorabfooafoorz'
```

where `'foo'.join('bar')` produced `'bfooafoor'`, which then was used to join the characters of `baz`.

Build a *list*, then return that:

```
if None in result.viewvalues():
    # one or more keys came back empty, abort
    return
serialized = ''.join([v for k, v in sorted(result.items())])
```

Comment: I'm confused, why is it `if v`? v should be a chunk of serialized data, why should it return `true`?

Comment: The `if v` was redundant, actually, but any non-empty string is considered true in a boolean context.